# T-SQL bug? CURSOR does not respect TABLESAMPLE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

Ran into this today. Code as follows, with tablesample commented out. Run it, get the expected results of 5000050000.

```
-- tested in SQL Server 2014

use tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ints', 'U') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP TABLE ints;

CREATE TABLE ints(x bigint NOT NULL);

WITH MakeInts AS
(
    SELECT CAST(1 AS bigint) AS x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT x + 1 AS x
    FROM MakeInts
    WHERE x < 100000
)
INSERT INTO ints 
    SELECT *
    FROM MakeInts
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);


DECLARE crsr CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR select x 
from ints
--tablesample (5 percent)
;

DECLARE @x bigint;
DECLARE @sum bigint = 0;
OPEN crsr;

FETCH NEXT FROM crsr INTO @x;
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
    BEGIN
        set @sum += @x;
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM crsr INTO @x;
END

CLOSE crsr;
DEALLOCATE crsr;

print @sum;
```

Now comment tablesample back in and run again. Same result of 5000050000.

Am I overlooking something completely obvious?

(Martin Smith's comment pointed out that tablesample samples at the page level and my table was small enough to fit on one page. Good catch, and amended code above so it makes a much larger table. Doesn't fix though)

Comment: Yeah, it's not working right. Try local static cursor and it's even worse, i get no rows at all :)

Comment: you can save the sampled data into another table and then do a cursor on that

Comment: @siggemannen - getting no rows at all is expected. The whole table only fits on a couple of pages so you should only expect to get anything at all about 1 in 10 times. `tablesample` is per page

Comment: Oh, right @MartinSmith, i remembered it being not-exactly deterministic, but not why :D Still, it seems different cursor hints lead to different results, just READ_ONLY seem to lead to whole thing being read

Comment: @MartinSmith: you are right, code amended to fill that hole, and thanks!

Comment: I presume it is just silently ignored. For the dynamic cursor in the question it only gets one row at a time and it would need to have logic to implement the table sampling logic every time fetching the next row would end up on a new page (rather than just doing a "fetch next"). For static it can implement it as it materialises the whole resultset into a work table - looks like static probably works as hoped for on the larger table? https://i.stack.imgur.com/RanUf.png

Comment: @MartinSmith: You're right again, it seems to be ignoring tablesample, and as you suggest, add INSENSITIVE and suddenly it starts to work. That's a couple of hours lost today. Nonetheless, a silent ignoring of an option is still a bug. It should not do this. If you write up your reply as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: in my previous work, using non-static / non-local cursors for non-updates was considered a mistake, so to me DECLARE CR_X CURSOR READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY LOCAL STATIC FOR ... is the way to go when doing cursor stuff

Comment: Interesting bug, but I'd love to know what you're doing that requires a cursor over `TABLESAMPLE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour isn't documented on the [`TABLESAMPLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#tablesample-clause) details so is somewhat speculative but certainly the demo in the question would indicate that the option is just being silently ignored.

For a dynamic cursor I can see why this might be the case. Dynamic cursor plans need to [support](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/properties-of-iterators/ba-p/383106) moving both forwards and backwards so this would require storing some additional cursor state for just this edge case and add complexity to the fetch next.

It does seem maybe a bug that it doesn't just silently change the type to static though (as it would if you added an `order by x` for example).

But in any event if you explicitly request static you do get the table sampling applied before the rows are inserted to the worktable.